# Como decompilar código de um módulo python usando marshal?

Tags: python

Gostaria de obter o bytecode de um módulo em Python e salvar em um pyc com marshal.

Exemplo:

abc

- test

  - module
- t2

  - mod2

Então, eu faria import abc.test.module e gostaria de obter o bytecode e assim salvar um pyc dele, a partir disso.

Comment: Veja se isso pode te ajudar. É um descompilador para Python: https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2

Comment: @SamirBraga uncompyle deixa muitos arquivos mal decompilados e incompletos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma boa ferramenta, porém descontinuada é o [**UnPyc**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unpyc/)(suporta as versões *2.5* e *2.6* do Python). Há relatos que esse descompilador consegue recuperar cerca de *90%* do arquivo original.

Também há o [**Easy Python Decompiler**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/) que é baseado em dois descompiladores([uncompyle2](https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2) e [decompyle++](https://github.com/zrax/pycdc)). O interessante é que suporta desde a versão *1.0* até a *3.3* do Python.

De atenção também ao módulo [**`py_compile`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/py_compile.html).